# Force the use of the shift key while pressing enter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, text-editor, keyboard-events

I have a window in which I would like to force the user to press the shift key when the enter key is pressed. I can easily cancel the event when only one key is pressed, but what I would really like is that when the user presses the enter key, it will react as if the user is also pressing the shift key.

Is there any way to do this. I must use the KeyDown event because apparently the control I must use does not have a key press event

Context is pretty simple. I have to use an already defined rich text box (I don't like it but I can't do otherwise) that I can't really modify, which generate a

tag when the user press enter but a 
 tag when the user press Shift-Enter. The user expressed concerns about this but doesn't want to teach its users to use Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

Code I have right now :

```
Private Sub F_EditeurRTF_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.Key = Key.Enter AndAlso Not My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
     'Add code to simulate user pressing the shift key at the same time.
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems my question is not clear. In simple word, I want to "fool" my editor into thinking the shift key was pressed even when it's not. This is only true when someone presses the enter key.

Comment: Hire a person to visit all your users, armed with a bottle of superglue, and glue their pinky to the shift key.

Comment: Put something heavy on the shift key? You're going to have to provide some context if you want a straight answer.

Comment: I'm confused about what the problems is.  What does Shift-Enter do that Enter by itself does not do?

Comment: Shift-Enter adds a line break while Enter adds a paragraph break. I would like to add a line break with Enter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here, based on the few details in your question, but tell me if this is what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        DoWork(e.Shift)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DoWork(ByVal ShiftIsDown As Boolean)
    If ShiftIsDown Then
        MessageBox.Show("Shift Pushed")
        'Do special work for the case when Shift + Enter is pressed
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Shift Not Pushed")
        'Do special work for the case when Enter alone is pressed
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Close but nope. I unfortunatly don't have much control over that is done or not om the rich text box (God I hate precompiled controls but I don't have a choice here). I wish I could do e.Shift = true then go on. I catch the keydown one control earlier with the preview because it seem the keydown on my rich text box won't (Another bad point for the RTB) and I can cancel the keydown it I don't get the shift, but that's it for now...

Comment: "...One control earlier?"  "...Preview?"  I'm not following you there.  Can you please post some of your source code?  This question is hard to follow.

Comment: in WPF, you can use tunneling events, meaning if my editor is found inside a grid, the grid will catch the keydown before the editor using the 'PreviewKeyDown' event. This is actually irrelevant in this case. The question is, can I "fool" the editor into thinking the shift was pressed even though it's not.